# Displaying json data as a list in jQuery mobile

Tags: javascript, python, json, google-app-engine, jquery-mobile

I am trying to retrieve a list of `Staff` entities from my datastore, and then display this as a list in my jQuery mobile app.
When i test this locally from my browser, it displays the data just fine like this:

```
[{"ID": "67", "Name": "Stevie Gerrad"},{"ID": "100", "Name": "Christiano Ronaldo"}]
```

But when i try it from my jQuery mobile app, nothing happens.Although there isn't any error and i get the status code:

`Status Code:   HTTP/1.1 200 OK.`

In my `Python` code, i have:

```
class Staff(ndb.Model):
    staff_id=ndb.IntegerProperty(required=True)
    staff_name=ndb.StringProperty(required=True)

def asJSONString(self):
    return '{"ID": "%s", "Name": "%s"}' % (self.staff_id, self.staff_name)

 def toTableRow(self):
     return "<tr><td>" + self.staff_id + "</td><td>" + self.staff_name + "</td></tr>"

class StaffHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        staff_id=self.request.get('id')
        callback=self.request.get('callback')
        staff=Staff.get_by_id(staff_id)

    if staff:
        self.response.write("A member with this id already exists")
    else:
        s_id = int(self.request.get('id'))
        s_name= self.request.get('name')
        staff=Staff(id=s_id, staff_id=s_id, staff_name=s_name)
        staff.put()
    if callback:
            self.response.write(callback + '(' + staff.toJSON() + ')')
    else:
            self.response.write(staff.toJSON())


   def getStaffList(callback):
      members_of_staff =  Staff.query()
      strList=""
      for staff in members_of_staff:
       if len(strList) > 0:
        strList+= ',' + staff.asJSONString()
    else:
        strList=staff.asJSONString()
     if callback=='':
        return '[' + strList + ']'
    else:
        return callback+ '([' + strList + ']);'

    class StaffViewHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
       def get(self):
          callback=self.request.get('callback')
          self.response.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
          self.response.out.write(getStaffList(callback))


  app=webapp2.WSGIApplication([

    ('/staff',StaffHandler),
    ('/viewStaffList', StaffViewHandler)

    ], debug=True)
```

And then in my `staff.js` file, i did something like this:

```
viewMembersURL = "http://localhost:8030/viewStaffList";

$ (document).ready(function() {

   $("#showMembers").bind('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    doViewMembersRequest();

    });
 });

 function doViewMembersRequest() {
     $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: viewMembersURL,
         async: true,
         jsonpCallback: 'handleResults',
         contentType: "application/json",
         dataType: 'jsonp'

    });
  }

 function formatStaffList(members) {
    var html = "<li><div>";
     html+="<p><strong>" + members.id + "</strong></p>" +
     "<h5>" + member.name + "</h5>";
      html+="</div></li>";
        return html;
    }

 function handleResults(members) {
    var i, list="";
     for (i=0; i<members.length; i +=1) {
      list+=formatStaffList(members[i]);
   }
    displayMembers(list);
   }

   function displayMembers(list) {
      $("#staff_members").html(list).listView();
   }
```

and finally, the portion of my `staff.html` code where i want to display the list upon the click of a button:

```
<div data-role="content">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="b" data-inset="true">
        <a href="#" id="showMembers" data-role="button" data-theme="b">Show Members</a>
    </ul>
    <ul id="staff_members" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
        <!--Members list to go in here-->
    </ul>
</div>
```

I'll really appreciate second thoughts on this.

**Update:**

I ran a couple of tests to see if i could display just the names.Somehow,i managed to get the `listview` to display this:

[image]

The number of items displayed matches the number of entities in my datastore. This means the communication with the server is fine. I think the problem is in the line

```
html+="<h5>" + members.name + "</h5>";
```

`member.name` isn't returning anything (tested with console.log()).

and if i change it to just

```
html+="<h5>" + members + "</h5>";
```

i get: `[object Object]` displayed in the listview. This tells me that am returning objects from the datastore and not strings as i would have expected.

Answer (score 1):

The source code all looks good. A process of elimination would help to close in on what is probably a subtle problem. Trace execution of your code by inserting console.log('message') or alert('message') calls in the functions in staff.js, also appending the data you expect to see in order to validate your design. I use similar code that works with json rather than jsonp, so that may be a factor.

Comment: Thanks Martin.I will try these.Just out of curiosity, what changes can i make to my code to work with just json?

Answer (score 1):

h5 tag is not closed properly while creating HTML.

```
function formatStaffList(members) {
var html = "<li><div>";
 html+="<p><strong>" + members.id + "</strong></p>" +
 "<h5>" + member.name + "</h5>"
  html+="</div></li>";
    return html;
}
```

Comment: How do you mean? You posted the same thing i posted in my question

Comment: check </h5> tag after member.name , its not closed in your code.

Comment: You mean with a semicolon?

Comment: No,i mean slash (/) before h5 (</h5>). Right now in you code its member.name + "<h5>" but correct should be member.name + "</h5>". Basically, h5 tag needs to be closed using '/'. Hope i am clear here.

Comment: Oh.I was checking your answer against my original code,not the one in the question.I already fixed that.I'll edit the question to reflect this.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue may be the sloppy handling of the id.  You pull it from the request as a string, then use `get_by_id()` which wants an integer.  And you store staff_id as an `IntegerProperty` but never cast it to a string when you build your strings.  Take proper care of that.  Use logging to make sure you are getting the results you expect at each process.

Comment: Yeah.  You pass "members" to formatStaffList, but return "member" in member.name, which is not defined.

Comment: Any suggestion on how to get past this? I have tried a lot of things like `members[i].staff_name` but it still doesn't work.How do i access these variable with the members being returned?

Comment: First, in `formatStaffList`, change "members" to "member" in both places, and in the function def.

Comment: Now what does the log say?  You should update, so we can see what your current code looks like.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53906/discussion-between-ojonugwa-ochalifu-and-gaefan)

Comment: Did you fix the string/integer discrepancies I noted above?

Comment: Sorry, I am heading out to enjoy the day.  No time for chat

Comment: Okay.Thanks for your time.I'll keep at it.

Answer (score 0):

Phew.With the help of `FireBug` I finally got this to work.I noticed that in the bottom right corner this was being shown:

[image]

it dawned on me that needed to provide the key of the json objects, instead of the variables i had in my datastore. So instead of

```
html+="<h5>" + members.name + "</h5>";
```

it had to be

```
html+="<h5>" + members.Name + "</h5>";
```

or

```
html+="<h5>" + members.ID + "</h5>";
```

problem solved.
`Name` appears to be a keyword, so i'll just change that to something else.

The result now is exactly what i wanted.

[image]